# 実行時にWPFかフォームかをDLL側から判定したい。

Tags: windows, c#, .net

WPF、Windows Forms問わずに共有されるライブラリ(dll)があるとして、
そのライブラリを呼び出したEXEがWPFなのか、フォームなのか、コンソールなのかを判定する方法は、ありませんか？

- リフレクションを使用する方法でも構いません。

[開発環境]
C# 6.0
.NET 4.5.1
VS2015 Preview

Answer (score 3):

`AppDomain`に`PresentationFramework.dll`が読み込まれていて、`System.Windows.Application.Current`がnullでない場合はWPFアプリと判断してよいと思います。  これはフォーム上で`ElementHost`を使用していても明示的に`Application`を作成しない限り有効です。

Answer (score 2):

もう少し目的をはっきりさせる必要があると思います。単にアセンブリを読み込んでいるだけ※の場合もありますし、スレッドプールから呼び出された場合にはスタックフレームには痕跡がないかもしれません。WPFがWinFormsをホストしたりその逆もできます。また、ILDASM.EXEのように敢えてコンソールアプリケーションとして起動してからフォームを開くものもあります。

※ [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx)が使いたくてWinFormsを読み込んだことがあります…。